# Nodejs async each inside each inside waterfall

Tags: node.js, async.js

I have been banging my head with this for way too long. Perhaps someone in here could help me a bit?

I have an object containing arrays of objects, and I need to do some manipulation for each object in turn before proceeding. Here's simplified example, one of many I've been trying:

```
    var demo = {
        one: ['1'],
        two: ['2'],
        three: ['3', '4', '5']
    };

    async.waterfall([
        function(callback) {
            console.log("Step 1");
            setTimeout(function() {
                    console.log("Doing stuff...");
                    callback(null, demo);
            }, 1000);
        },
        function(prevData, callback) {
            console.log("Step 2");
            async.each(prevData, function(obj) {
                async.each(obj, function(item, callback2) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                            console.log("Doing stuff for item: "+item);
                            callback2(null, demo);
                    }, 1000);
                });
            });
            callback(null, demo);
        }
    ], function(err) {
        if(err) {
            alertify.error("Unhandled exception: "+err);
        } else {
            console.log("All stuff done.");
        }
    });
```

What I am expecting, is:

```
Step 1
Doing stuff...
Step 2
Doing stuff for item: 1
Doing stuff for item: 2
Doing stuff for item: 3
Doing stuff for item: 4
Doing stuff for item: 5
All stuff done.
```

But what I get:

```
Step 1
Doing stuff...
Step 2
All stuff done.
Doing stuff for item: 1
Doing stuff for item: 2
Doing stuff for item: 3
Doing stuff for item: 4
Doing stuff for item: 5
```

If been trying, probably, every combination of callbacks from each level that I can think of, except the correct one. Must be obvious but I just don't get it...

The sequence itself is right but the function that should manipulate the items does not execute before later.

Comment: Oops, thanks for the catch. Fixed it in my test code for the output but forgot to update the code snippet I pasted in here. Updated now.

Comment: Your code will be more readable if you extract the functions out instead of making them inline, As it is it is very difficult to read. [Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/sellomkantjwa/a8c3dd058c26646ea666312b61f82908) where some of the functions are not inline:

Comment: So true. The final code will be with extacted functions, this is to figure out the problem and demonstrate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this portion:

```
    function(prevData, callback) {
        console.log("Step 2");
        async.each(prevData, function(obj) {
            async.each(obj, function(item, callback2) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                        console.log("Doing stuff for item: "+item);
                        callback2(null, demo);
                }, 1000);
            });
        });
        callback(null, demo);
    }
```

Immediately after the `async.each`, you call `callback(null, demo);`. This is before async.each is done. You need to call `callback` only once the async.each is done. you do this by adding another  callback as a third parameter to the `async.each`, like so:

```
function (prevData, callback) {
    console.log("Step 2");
    async.each(prevData, function (obj) {
        async.each(obj, function (item, callback2) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                console.log("Doing stuff for item: " + item);
                callback2(null, demo);
            }, 1000);
        });
    }, function asyncEachDone(err) {
        callback(err, prevData)
    })
}
```

Comment: That solved it. I had to add one more callback after the inner async.each is done but that was it. Thanks!